# PCA 3D matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, pca

I'm trying to apply a PCA solution to a 3d matrix (x,y,z) 
I have 552 occurences of this matrix to use as my sample.
I'm not trying to reduce the dimensionality, instead I want to be able to predict these matrix using the information that I will extract from the first 3 vectors of the PCA.

I searched online but I couldn't find any clear solution to that problem.

One approach that I thought was to "unwrap" my 3d matrix on a 2d set of information
so, for instance assuming that I have a matrix that is 
  C    D
A 1.5  2.4
B 2    3.4

I could work with the linear combination
(A,C) (A,D) (C,B) (B,D)
1.5    2.4    2    3.4

As my variables

Does it make sense?
Am I missing something?
is there any easier way ?

Looking forward to hear other members !

Cheers,

Comment: C   D
A 
B 

That is my matrix
AXC = 1.5
AXD = 2.4
CXB = 2
BXD = 3.4

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you want to add additional information to your question, you can edit your post.